# xcode iphone particles without cocos2D

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone, particles

is it possible to have particles without using cocos 2D. I know particle designer but we have to use it with cocos 2D. How can I make particles without cocos 2D ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a particle system on iphone and retain the created particles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913124/how-to-create-a-particle-system-on-iphone-and-retain-the-created-particles)

Comment: vous devez vous rendre à chaque question que vous avez déjà demandé et cliquez sur la case à cocher par la réponse la plus appropriée à l'accepter. Aider les gens à obtenir la reconnaissance. Si vous n'avez pas "accepter" les réponses en cochant les gens sont moins susceptibles d'aider. Vous devez augmenter votre "accepter taux« aussi proche que possible de 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by spawning an image and adding it to an array, which makes it extremly easy to animate the image or do whatever with it.

```
    - (void)createImage {

    UIImageView *Image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random() % 320, 480, 40, 40)];
    [Image setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:Image];
    [myArray addObject:Image];

}
```

That creates a black image wherever and adds it to an array.

Then, you can make a timer and spawn the image every second!

```
spawn = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/3 target:self selector:@selector(Spawn) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


- (void)Spawn {

    [self createImage];

}
```

Comment: is there another way for real particles ?

Comment: i've been using this way and it worked, but i'm sure there are other ways - i think this one's the easiest (not counting cocos2d :D ).

Comment: Yea, for it to be more complex would require a particle engine and/or heavy use of OpenGLes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to go right to [71Squared](http://www.71squared.com/2009/05/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-8-particle-emitter/). He provides videos of creating a very cool particle engine without Cocos2d. Then, once you have your particle emitter workin, you can go ahead and create a simple class to store the particle sets if you want - I did this for my app.

Comment: yas I se it but there are many functionnality of particles like start point  or end point that are not on this tutorial. Is there another way ?