# Import particle from cocos 2d project to non-cocos2d project

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, particles

I have created particle in cosos 2d and I want to import my particle into my real project (non cocos2) project, How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible because of the following:

The cocos 2d library contains lots of different classes that are responsible for things like particles, sounds and effects.

If you would like to import a particle, you would need to import the whole library which would make your non-cocos2d project into a cocos2d project.

Not too long ago, i answered a question about [particle creation outside of cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706096/xcode-iphone-particles-without-cocos2d) you might check it out. The answer is about spawning images, adding them to an array and animating them via the array.

You can also make particles with openGLES which would be a bit harder...

Comment: but if I import all the library of cocos2d it should work. For exemple tiny wings has particles created with particle designer but the application is not made by cocos2d

Comment: yes, but it is going to be a cocos2d app cuase' you used their libraries. i suppose you could write an email to the guys working at cocos and ask them if you may use their particle libraries. I doubt that they would give it to you just like that, but such thing is always worth a try :D